# Unexpected attribute 'name' for object of type Index

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

python newbie here plz help

```
indexes:


# AUTOGENERATED
# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.

 - kind: Post 
 properties: 
 - name: user 
 - name: created 
   direction: desc

   - kind: Post
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: created
    direction: desc

- kind: Post
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

the error formed here is Unexpected attribute 'name' for object of type Index.
this occurs when the following command is used

```
gcloud deploy app index.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your yaml file's indentation is wrong, it should be like this:

```
indexes:


# AUTOGENERATED
# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.

- kind: Post 
  properties: 
  - name: user 
  - name: created 
    direction: desc

- kind: Post
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: created
    direction: desc

- kind: Post
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```